# How to use my computer as a Headset device for my phone with Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, toshiba-stack

I want to extract the audio from my phone (the analog TV and FM/AM receiver mainly) and play it through my computer speakers. There is a headphone jack but it is of non-standard size (probably a micro-jack) and I do not have access to a shop that sells that kind of equipment in my area so doing this with Bluetooth is the only solution I can foresee.

Both my laptop and my phone support A2DP but for some reason the service (from the phone) does not show up while I add a new connection and the phone does not let me initiate a connection with any other profile except FTP (although it detects other services in the service list like A2DP and works perfectly fine with other profiles like DUN, HID, OPP, SSP if the connection is started through the computer).

I am currently using the latest version of the Toshiba stack, I have tried using WIDCOMM but it refuses to install drivers for both the internal Bluetooth (which is a Broadcom device) and the USB Bluetooth that I use on my desktop. The standard Microsoft stack (generic driver) does install but it does not work with both of my devices as they do not detect any Bluetooth devices when scanning. With BlueSoleil (the default stack that came with the USB Bluetooth) I could set my device as "headset" instead of only "laptop/desktop", and this allowed both my phones to detect my laptop as a device they can use as a headset, but the problem with this stack was that only the older phone could actually connect to my laptop and that the internal Bluetooth could not be used.

Basically, I want to set the device type as a "headset" for my phone using the Toshiba stack like I did with BlueSoleil. Is there any way this could be done?

Device type selection:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you'll need windows media player to connect to the device to handle the audio.

here's what looks like a complete guide:

http://www.guidingtech.com/12120/stream-songs-phone-to-computer-bluetooth/

Comment: Thank you, but the Microsoft Bluetooth enumerator does not seem communicate with both of my Bluetooth devices, so I cannot connect directly by Bluetooth. I tried connecting my phone through COM15 (the only port available for use by both programs) with the Windows Mobile Device Center that I made with the Toshiba Stack and it still could not detect anything.

Comment: I think that your question is ultimately 'How do I make bluetooth work ... at all'  which is kindof a broader question.